# A question on arithmetic progressions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, ramsey-theory

Is it true that for every $n \in \mathbb N$ , $\exists N \in \mathbb N$ such that for any subset $A \subseteq \{1,2,...,N\}$ , either $A$ or $\{1,2,..,N\} \setminus A$ contains an arithmetic progression of length $n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Color all the points in $A$ red and color all the rest of the points blue. By [Van der Waerden's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem), if $N = W(2, n)$, then one of these colors must have an arithmetic progression of length $n$.